# Questions regarding marriage

Tags: dharma, marriage, women, men, age

I am ofc going to be single, so this rule doesn't apply to me, but what I want to know is when a boy and girl would formally marry. Then, when that marriage is consummated. What is the punishment for early consummation? What happens if a marriage doesn't happen around this time to the man or woman? Is it different for different Varnas? Are there exceptions to these rules? Please provide scriptural references for all of this preferably from one text and a pdf so I can view such myself. Thank you!